# Can I ask for a Solution Manual of an Information Security Textbook?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, asking-questions

I am an M.Sc. student in Information Security/ CyberSecurity/ Cryptography. I want to ask for a very famous textbook's solution manual, is it okay? Also, I want to ask for recommendations for exam/solutions that I can find online so that I can practice. I know some universities supply such resources to their students for preparation, but mine does not. So, I want to ask users also for such resources.

The topic of all the aforementioned problems is straightly information security, so I believe I should be able to ask such things, but I wanted to double-check.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Asking for books/resources is off-topic. Asking for recommendations for products/services is also off-topic.

It's not about the subject matter, but it's a quirk of us being a Q&A site.

Comment: Do you know any forum that I can ask such things about Information Security?

Comment: Lots of forums out there. Reddit has a few subreddits. There are also lots of exam prep forums.